# How to display label & value on pie slice apex charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, apexcharts

I am using apex chart in angular app to display charts. working on pie chart & wanted to customise pie chart, display label on value both on pie slice as displayed in attached image. not found any solution for this please help any lead would be very helpful.
Thank you.

screenshot [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMcHk.png

```js
import { ChartComponent, ApexLegend, ApexDataLabels, ApexFill, ApexPlotOptions, ApexNonAxisChartSeries, ApexResponsive, ApexChart } from 'ng-apexcharts';

export interface ChartOptions {
  series: ApexNonAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  responsive: ApexResponsive[];
  labels: any[];
  legend: ApexLegend;
  dataLabels: ApexDataLabels;
  fill: ApexFill;
  plotOptions: ApexPlotOptions;
}

export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('chart') chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [70.48, 29.52],
      chart: {
        width: 380,
        type: 'pie',
        toolbar: {
          tools: {
            download: false,
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        show: false,
      },
      labels: ['DII', 'FII'],
      fill: {
        colors: ['#ffe163', '#694fb6'],
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          startAngle: 110,
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '14',
          fontWeight: '600',
          colors: ['#000000', '#ffffff'],
        },
        // formatter: function (val) {
        //   return val + "%";
        // }
      },
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 400,
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<apx-chart
    [series]="chartOptions.series"
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
    [labels]="chartOptions.labels"
    [responsive]="chartOptions.responsive"
    [legend]="chartOptions.legend"
    [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
    [fill]="chartOptions.fill"
    [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
  ></apx-chart>
```

Answer (score 3):

**To display labels and values on pie chart slices as you attached to the screenshot.**

We can make use of dataLabels option for customising the label.

Please add below two options to your chart options and also pass these two options on the `<apex-chart></apex-chart>` component in your HTML file

```
dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val, opt) {
          // return [] used to change the line for the labels
          // each index element will get rendered to a new line
          /* Also casted to know (unknown) first and then to (string) as library is currently 
             accepting return type as string only. so it's a small manipulation 
             until library does not accept array. */
          switch (opt.seriesIndex) { // seriesIndex gives the position of slice
            case 0:
              return [ 'Housing', '$000.00 | ' + val as string + '%' ] as unknown as string;
            case 1:
              return [ 'Credit', '$000.00 | ' + val as string + '%' ] as unknown as string;
            case 2:
              return [ 'Transportation', '$000.00 | ' + val as string + '%' ] as unknown as string;
            case 3:
              return [ 'Living', '$000.00 | ' + val as string + '%' ] as unknown as string;
            case 4:
              return [ 'Miscellaneous', '$000.00 | ' + val as string + '%' ] as unknown as string;
            default:
              return val as string;
          }
        },
        style: {
          fontSize: "13",
          colors: ['#404040'],
          fontWeight: '100',
          fontFamily: 'Arial'
        },
},
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          dataLabels: {
            offset: 20, // Moving the label position on slice
          }
        }
}
```

**The above options will help to show the labels as shown in below image**

[image: Rendered screenshot]

Hope this will help you or somebody else! Thanks.

Happy Coding :-)